# Chrome having issues handling filename HTTP header?

Tags: google-chrome, http

When download a file from chrome with single quoting in it, it downloads the file but with the name of the URL. If I remove the single quoting from the filename, the file is download normally. This only happens in Chrome. Internet Explorer and Firefox works just fine.

Chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 m

HTTP REQUEST

```
Request URL:http://server/Service.do?csrfToken=abcd
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Lettre%20d'exp%C3%A9rience.rtf
```

This will offer to download a file with name "Service.do". If I remove the single quoting out the name, it will offer to download a file with the right name.

Is there a workaround for this? (Other than changing the filename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to percent-encode that single quote in the name.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Lettre%20d%27exp%C3%A9rience.rtf
```

Also, [RFC 6266 Appendix D](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#appendix-D) recommends that you add a plain `filename` parameter as an **ASCII-only** fallback for older user agents that may not implement `filename*`:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Lettre d'experience.rtf"; filename*=UTF-8''Lettre%20d%27exp%C3%A9rience.rtf
```

Comment: But this is an issue only in Chrome. Can be this considered to be a Chrome bug?. Or it is simply that the browser don't implement the RFC?. It seems strange that this happens in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: @GabrielEspinel Leaving that single quote unencoded is a violation of [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987). So, on the contrary, Firefox is [generous to your mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle).

Comment: I see. That make sense. Thanks